# File location in project after deploying to JBoss

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, location, wildfly

I am trying to get the file location of a file in my project after deploying the project to JBoss via a `.war` file. This program exposes a couple of web services (using SOAP).

Here is the directory structure in Eclipse:

```
ProjectName 
|-Java Resources
 |-src
 |  +package.one
 |  +package.two
 |  ...
 |-docs
 |  myFile.xsd
 |  otherFile.xml
|-WebContent
 |+META-INF
 |-WEB-INF
 | +lib
 | web.xml
 |index.jsp
```

Normally, if I have a Java class inside of `package.one`, the file path to `myFile.xsd` would be `../ProjectName/docs/myFile.xsd`. This works fine if I code a `main` method.

Once I deploy this project on JBoss, however, it cannot find the file. JBoss starts looking inside its `bin` folder. The actual project is deployed to `{wildflyHome}/standalone/deployments/ProjectName.war`. So I'm not sure why it's looking inside the `bin` folder.

I get this error trying to access `myFile.xsd`:

```
08:36:47,908 ERROR [stderr] (default task-3) org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'file:/C:/Users/Flow/Documents/Tools/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/bin/../ProjectName/docs/myFile.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

I rooted out option 2 and 3 because it works perfectly fine if not deployed on server as mentioned above.

How would I access the file once it's on the server?

Comment: What are you attempting to access the file? Generally it's better to get it as a resource stream, `SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/docs/myFile.xsd")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying for long time, I finally gave up and just put the files in the `bin` folder.

I made a folder in the `bin` folder. From there the filepath was just the `folder/file.ext`.